# Reppy behaving strangely with certain entries

Tags: python, robots.txt

I was testing Reppy with google.com.robots.txt, but with certain entries it went a bit wayward.

Below are those:
`Disallow: /alerts/` ,  must get a False here.
`Allow: /alerts/$` ,  must get a True here.

I am getting `True` for the 1st and `False` for the 2nd entry.
While, I got correct results with the rest of the entries.

```
>>> import reppy  
>>> from reppy.cache import RobotsCache  
>>> robots = RobotsCache()  
>>> rules = robots.fetch("http://google.com")  
>>> rules.allowed('/search', 't')  
False    
>>> rules.allowed('/search/about', 't')
True

#While things are right above, they are unexpected below

>>> rules.allowed('/alerts/', 't')
True    # FALSE is expected here
>>> rules.allowed('/alerts/$', 't')
False   # TRUE is expected here
>>>
```

I'd be thankful if someone gives me a hint where to look at to rectify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$` is not a literal `$`, it means "end of the URL".

Take a look at [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt#url-matching-based-on-path-values):

> Google, Bing, Yahoo, and Ask support a limited form of "wildcards" for
>   path values. These are:
>
> - `*` designates 0 or more instances of any valid character
> - `$` designates the end of the URL

So these rules:

```
Allow: /alerts/manage
Allow: /alerts/remove
Disallow: /alerts/
Allow: /alerts/$
```

Mean that you can access `/alerts/manage`, `/alerts/remove`, and `/alerts/`, but not any other child of `/alerts/` (e.g., `/alerts/foo`).  So the results you are seeing are accurate:

This returns true because it matches `Allow: /alerts/$`:

```
>>> rules.allowed('/alerts/', 't')
True
```

This returns false because it matches `Disallow: /alerts/`:

```
>>> rules.allowed('/alerts/$', 't')
False
```

Comment: Thank you! Totally understood that.